Slow data retrieval with stored procedures and SqlDataAdapter/SqlDataReader
I have a website that I've previously built as a personal/learning project in ASP.NET Webforms (up to 4.8) and I'm trying to convert it to ASP.NET Core 8.0 as my first project. This project has a fair bit of complex logic e.g. SQL Server stored procedures that retrieve data from multiple tables that I've previously retrieved as datasets and displayed on the site accordingly.
This is where I get stuck on my new site. Because of those stored procedures, I tried to use both SqlServer.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to try and retrieve the data and store it to a dataset, which I then take and convert to my corresponding class(es) from there. The issue is in the retrieval portion; using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, I've been able to isolate the bottlenecks to the initial opening of the connection and the loading of the data into a dataset or datatable (I tried this with both SqlDataAdapter and SqlDataReader). In some cases, the connection opening is 30-35% of the time elapsed with another 55-60% being associated with the loading of the data.
From what little I can gather, it seems to be an overall issue with ASP.NET Core 8.0, but it's not clear what issue it is and how to resolve it. Is it in the various Data.SqlClient namespaces somewhere? Does it have anything to do with the connection string (as in are there new ones that make better use of ASP.NET Core?) What am I looking for in order to diagnose/solve this?

As you're on .NET 8, you can safely remove all references to System.Data.SqlClient - even EF6.5 (recently released) now supports Microsoft.Data.SqlClient now too.

No-one should be using SqlDataAdapter btw. Everyone seems to follow the same (awful) C#/ASP.NET "tutorial"  content published 20+ years ago that uses a SqlDataAdapter to populate untyped DataTable objects without realising how computationally-wasteful it all was/is (because DbDataAdapter was always meant for 2-way data modification so it's very stateful) - but for a webpage you only need 1-way data flow. Fortunately, now, with EF/EFCore it's definitely far easier to use strongly-typed entity objects, populated from a type-safe Linq-to-Entities IQueryable<>.

"From what little I can gather, it seems to be an overall issue with ASP.NET Core 8.0, but it's not clear what issue it is and how to resolve it" - We can't help you, sorry, because investigating perf issues like these requires doing the legwork to run a performance-profiler and traces - and then analyze all that data (e.g. ETL traces in WPA, or at least VS's built-in profiler with its relatively shallow learning-curve).

...though I'll say that SqlDataAdapter (and all DbDataAdapter subclasses, actually) use blocking IO and don't make use of async-IO - which will chew-up things in ASP.NET Core (which famously will punish you if you use non-async-IO by default). So that's a starting-point if you're stuck for ideas - but your profiler will give you much better info than my idle speculation.

I never used a data adaptor to fill a data table UNLESS you want to "adapt" the data (adaptor = updating of data). So, you use SQL command object, and then you can go MyDataTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader()). Or often better yet, you use the data table load method (async) such as MyTable.Load(Await cmdSQL.ExecuteReaderAsync()). So, I don't load up ado.net data tables with a data adaptor, and there was never any reason to do so, even when using .net framework vs that of .net core. As for speed? Built in datatable.load is MUCH faster then reading to some custom class. EF or ORM's are slow

For SQL the easiest is to use a lightweight ORM like Dapper, we are using it in our asp.net Core8 webservice. Having that said, it is not because we don't have this performance issue that it will solve yours, as I don't have a clue where exact your problem is, but using dapper will surely make your development life a lot easier

If it's purely the connection opening that's slow, then probably an issue with: slow TLS certificate validation, or server overload, or network issue.

@AlbertD.Kallal The DataTable.Load method you're referring to does actually use DataAdapter internally - the Common.LoadAdapter type wraps/proxies the actual ADO.NET DbDataAdapter it got from the IDataReader you passed into it.

That's true, but I don't declare a data adaptor object. As I noted, in most cases, the native ado.net objects tend to run MUCH faster then ORM's anyway.  And while there is a built in data adaptor, you still are read only unless you create a SQL command builder object - so the wiring parts to allow updates of such data is not created. And as noted, the other bonus is  you can use the async methods this way with great ease.  I mean, who's going to write  a loop with a reader? While I do like lightweight Dapper, ORM'S in most cases gobble up a whole lot more performance then native options

When you use a ORM's, you going to wind up using a reader anyway. The issue is how the translation works from that reader to the ORM's use of class's. Just saying this is not some 0 or 1 narrative here - both have merits, but in performance area, native objects tend to have less layers of moving parts then ORM's.  This suggests the culprit here is not that some data adaptor comes into play, but something else is causing the performance hit.  As noted, the poster will have to post some sample code for us to have a better idea (guess) as to what is going on here.
